# Instantiating Controller for testing with Jasmine / Getting Argument 'XY' is not a function, got undefined when running Jasmine test/spec

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

am trying to write a simple test for a controller in my app. The controller uses a service to send an AJAX request (i.e. really I am testing controller and service).
Am using Jasmine (which I am using for the first time) and also I am trying to stay close to the following example form the Angular Documentation:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$httpBackend

When I run my test I get the following error(s):

```
Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'LoginController' is not a function, got undefined http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.16/ng/areq?p0=LoginController&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined
    at http://localhost:8080/FreelancerDB_GUI/js/angular.js:78:12
    at assertArg (http://localhost:8080/FreelancerDB_GUI/js/angular.js:1443:11)
    at assertArgFn (http://localhost:8080/FreelancerDB_GUI/js/angular.js:1453:3)
    at http://localhost:8080/FreelancerDB_GUI/js/angular.js:7131:9
    at createController (http://localhost:8080/FreelancerDB_GUI/app/unittests/spec/loginSpec.js:37:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/FreelancerDB_GUI/app/unittests/spec/loginSpec.js:48:27)
    at attemptSync (http://localhost:8080/FreelancerDB_GUI/app/unittests/lib/jasmine-2.0.3/jasmine.js:1620:12)
    at QueueRunner.run (http://localhost:8080/FreelancerDB_GUI/app/unittests/lib/jasmine-2.0.3/jasmine.js:1608:9)
    at QueueRunner.execute (http://localhost:8080/FreelancerDB_GUI/app/unittests/lib/jasmine-2.0.3/jasmine.js:1595:10)
    at Spec.Env.queueRunnerFactory (http://localhost:8080/FreelancerDB_GUI/app/unittests/lib/jasmine-2.0.3/jasmine.js:508:35)
```

And further:

```
Error: Unsatisfied requests: POST http://localhost:8080/FreelancerDB_desktop/services/authentication/login?mandator=Devoteam&password=ae94be3cd532ce4a025884
```

I believe the second error only happens because things break beforehand...

My problem seems to be that I define my controller in a different way than it is done in the example. The example writes the controller as a simple function, whereas I define it in the following way:

```
angular.module('CVGenAppControllers')
    .controller('LoginController', ['$scope','$http','$state','UserService', '$translate','LoginService',
        function($scope, $http, $state, userService, $translate, loginService) {

            $scope.login = function() {
                ...
                loginService.login(params).then(success, error);
            };

            function success(p){

               ...
            }


            function error(p){
                ...
            }


            $scope.init = function () {
                ...
            };
            $scope.init();
        }
    ]
    );
```

Here is also my actual test spec:

```
describe('LoginControllerTest', function() {
       var $httpBackend, $rootScope, createController, authRequestHandler;

       module('CVGenAppControllers');
       beforeEach(inject(function($injector) {

         $httpBackend = $injector.get('$httpBackend');
         testurl = server + '/authentication/login' + '?mandator=Devoteam&password=ae94be3cd532ce4a025884';

         authRequestHandler = $httpBackend.when('POST', testurl)
                                .respond(
                                        {   "status":true,
                                            "message":"Login success",
                                            "content":{
                                                "uuid":"db8a6091-0c31-11e4-91f1-546318596611",
                                                "identityName":"Manager",
                                                "firstName":"Manfred",
                                                "lastName":"Manager",
                                                "mandator":"Devoteam",
                                                "roles":["freelancerDB-Admin-Role","UM-Manager-Role"],
                                                "rights":["um_disable_user_own_mandator","um_enable_user_any_mandator","um_write_user_own_mandator","um_enable_user_own_mandator","um_read_mandators_with_users","um_read_own_mandator_with_users","um_write_user_any_mandator","um_read_mandators_with_roles","um_write_any_mandator","um_disable_user_any_mandator","um_change_password","um_write_role_any_mandator","cvg_r_personaldata_owndata"]
                                            }
                                        }
                                );


         $rootScope = $injector.get('$rootScope');


         var $controller = $injector.get('$controller');

         createController = function() {
           return $controller('LoginController', {'$scope' : $rootScope });
         };
       }));

       afterEach(function() {
         $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation();
         $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();
       });

       it('should fetch authentication token', function() {
         $httpBackend.expectPOST(testurl);
         var controller = createController();
         $httpBackend.flush();

       });

    });
```

I have looked through quite a few previously asked questions, some of which seem to deal with routing problems in addition to the problem described here, sorry if it is a duplicate question nevertheless.
How should I write my test and how should the controller be declared to fix the problem?
Any help on how I can fix this will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I should add, that i do not intend to really change the way I declare my controller, as I believe this is a good/better way (please correct me if I am wrong). I would really like to know, what I can do to fix my test.